How overlapping events are not sorted by duration in odoo calendar
I need them to be ordered by start date and then by creation date or by sequence, not by duration, every time I resize an event o render calendar
enter image description here
I hope that when adding an event of the same date and time it is ordered by start date as it works, by another criterion for example start date or it is not ordered, simply add the event and it is not ordered
Check in the Odoo runbot and it is being ordered correctly, how do I achieve that?
I tested with the eventverlap property but it doesn't work, I tried to sort but it doesn't work...
I hope that when adding an event of the same date and time it is ordered by start date as it works, by another criterion for example start date or it is not ordered, simply add the event and it is not ordered
